# Silverlight/Flash webcast software, similar to Channel 9 PDC 2008

Tags: silverlight, flash

Anyone have recommendations for webcast software, similar to the Silverlight app here: http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL57/

I looked at a couple other questions posted here, but I don't want a hosted solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a pre-built solution or advice for creating your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDC Channel 9 Site is using the player base from http://codeplex.com/SL2VideoPlayer with some of their modifications (which we plan to roll into that project).  They have a Windows Media Streaming server back-end delivering the media.

Answer (score 0):

For Flash there is [JW FLV Player](http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=JW_FLV_Player). Just put the files on your own web server. On CodePlex you can find a [Silverlight 2.0 media player](http://www.codeplex.com/sl2videoplayer).